# While testing basic Nodejs CRUD API using postman, it gives error 'Cannot Post'. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, postman

I have created a basic Nodejs CRUD and authentication API.
While testing the basic create operation of a new order using Postman, it gives back the status code `404`with response body 'Cannot Post'.

Error:

```
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /order/addorder</pre>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The API logic seems to be correct for me and the routers too.

```
module.exports.add_order = auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { productName, quantity } = req.body;
        if (!productName || !quantity)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Not all fields have been entered" });
        const existingorder = await Order.findOne({ productName });
        if (existingorder)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "A product with this name already exists" });
        
        const newOrder = await new Order({
            productName,
            quantity,
            userId: auth.user,
            timestamp
        });
        const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
        res.json(savedOrder);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
    
}
```

The `auth` function is a middleware function which verifies the JWT.

Router:

```
orderrouter.get('/readorder', ordercontroller.read_order);
orderrouter.post('/addorder', ordercontroller.add_order);
orderrouter.put('/updateorder', ordercontroller.update_order);
orderrouter.delete('/deleteorder', ordercontroller.delete_order);
 


module.exports = orderrouter;
```

Comment: What your code currently does is this: `module.exports.add_order = auth;` and then it creates an `async` function which is not used. Make this an Array: `module.exports.add_order = [auth, async (req, res) => {}];`. Also, just in case, since you didn't show this part, are you correctly declaring `app.use('/order', orderrouter);`?

Comment: Yes, I have declared  `app.use('/order', orderrouter);` function in the main `server.js` file. And the array method worked. But I didn't understand how that worked.

Comment: When you're declaring a route, you are passing it middleware. Sometimes, you just have 1 middleware (your own function); `app.post('/foo', () => {})`, and sometimes you have multiple ones you want to chain by passing them as separate parameters: `app.post('/foo', auth, () => {})`. But for convenience, Express also allows you to pass an Array, instead of different parameters. For use cases just like yours: `app.post('/foo", [auth, () => {}])`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

The error says you are accesing **/order/addorder** but in your router you only have **/addorder**.

Make sure your group routes have the **/order** prefix